# Only tester user can publish on his wall with Facebook SDK v4 PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

My app allows to a signed user to post a custom message on his wall.

The app only works with the account which holds the app and the users marked as testers, but for regular users it seems that the APP can't get publish_actions permission. For tester users when the guy logs in first it asks for regular permissions and the second windows is the message that the app wants to publish on the wall, this second message never happens for regular users.

I've submited my app for review (although the website is not on a public server) and it got rejected for  not explaining well how the user use this right. Does the app have to be approved here to work... or is this just for showing up on the facebook searcher and stuff...??

Thanks

Comment: I think this happens because your app needs to be approved- otherwise, it would be possible for anyone to publish their app with extended permissions without the approval by the facebook team

Comment: yep, I saw that a minute ago in other forum... do you now if the app can be approved even though the app is still not online?

Comment: I think so, as facebook team should be able to test it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for permissions to be approved, you must:

1. Make sure the website or application is accessible to the public (so Facebook can test). The app can be on a private / unpublished page.
2. Provide detailed instructions and screenshots on how the permission is used. This is so that Facebook can check to see if it complies with the Platform Policies and that the app is not spammy
3. Make sure your app complies with the Platform Policies before submitting for review.

For the purpose of review, you should make the application available to the public. Once the permission is approved, you can then remove public access to the application.